# Using Excel Unique function to find values in the same columns of all the sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file to automate name in my projects, and it has variable number of sheets  depends on the the project. I need to find and list all the names in a specific column of all the sheets without duplication. For instance here:

| Sheet A Column C | Sheet B Column C | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mario | Robert | Mario |
| David | Bernard | Robert |
| Kevin | David | Bernard |
|  | Mario | Kevin |
|  |  | David |

Since there is a new UNIQUE function in Excel 2021, I tried to use it, but I cannot figure out how to organize the array reference inside the function to consider distinctive column in all the sheets.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307927/ignore-duplicates-and-create-new-list-of-unique-values-in-excel

Answer (score 2):

It looks like we can't use 3D references in the UNIQUE function, so we can first append one array of text to another:

```
=LET(
     a,Sheet1!C1:C3,
     b,Sheet2!C1:C4,
     tr,ROWS(a)+ROWS(b),
     MAKEARRAY(
               tr,
               1,
               LAMBDA(
                     r,
                     c,
                     IF(
                        r<=ROWS(a),
                        INDEX(a,r),
                        INDEX(b,r-ROWS(a))
                       )
                     )
              )
    )
```

So, let `a` be the data in `Sheet1!C1:C3` and let `b` be the data in `Sheet2!C1:C4`. Let `tr` be the sum of rows of `a` and the rows of `b` (i.e. the total rows). Then, make an array which is `tr` rows tall and `1` column wide. Populate the array as follows: For the row `r` whose index is less than or equal to the length of `a`, use the value from the same index in `a`. For a row `r` whose index is greater than the length of `a`, use the value from `b` whose index is the index of `r` minus the length of `a`.

I've created a LAMBDA called ARRAYUNION so I can re-use this in the future. Here's the formula:

```
=LAMBDA(a,b,LET(r,ROWS(a)+ROWS(b),MAKEARRAY(r,1,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(r<=ROWS(a),INDEX(a,r),INDEX(b,r-ROWS(a)))))))
```

And here you can see the usage.

[image]

Inspired by [excel-ticker.de](http://www.excel-ticker.de/summary-of-my-custom-lambdas-for-arrays/), [mrexcel.com](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/unique-of-rectangular-range-using-makearray-in-excel-2416.1177980/) with some learning from [sumproduct.com](https://www.sumproduct.com/blog/article/a-to-z-of-excel-functions/the-makearray-function). The first reference has a much more comprehensive implementation which handles multi-column arrays and provides default values. My view was it was a little too complex for this question, so I created something a little simpler.

Comment: +1 for the use LAMBDA.

Comment: Thanks @FlexYourData for your respond. It seems pretty much straightforward, but the table provided was just an example. In reality number of sheets are changing from excel file to another (depend on project), the only fixed parameter here is column of data in every sheet. How that might affect your formula then.

Answer (score 0):

I take a different approach (not being a special person with `LAMBDA()` and the various (eight or so is it?) functions like `MAKEARRAY()` that will come with it some year).

Suppose three sheets and a common column (Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3 using column F here). The formula goes like so:

```
=LET(AllSheets, CHOOSE({1,2,3},  Sheet2!F1:F10,  Sheet3!F1:F10,  Sheet4!F1:F10  ),

      UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<Group><Element>"& TEXTJOIN("</Element><Element>",TRUE,AllSheets)& "</Element></Group>","/*/*"))
 )
```

Some very simple things in it:

1. Using `LET()` allows one to place all the elements that need edited at the immediate start of the formula so one need not do the equivalent of dumpster diving to edit ranges and such. Notice the parentheses around the series of ranges for the Name `AllSheets`:  That lets you use as many as you like with great ease.
2. `AllSheets` is then the starting input in the working formula. It is the second parameter of `CHOOSE()`, the items `CHOOSE()` is to select from.
3. `CHOOSE()` will actually select all the choices in your usage here. That's what the `{1,2,3}` does. That's just a formula writing creation though. For the final formula, you would want to use `SEQUENCE()` to create the list since you might have many sheets and not care to hand-type a list like that one.
4. Selecting all the choices builds a 2-D table with one column for each sheet you include, and however many rows. Any cells in the ranges you gave to `AllSheets` will show as 0's in this internal table. That "extra" and unwanted material is not a problem because of the next layer. `CHOOSE()` is used because it does not mind drawing data from more than one sheet in the same use of it. `INDEX()` is how I usually do this, but I have never drawn on more than one sheet and discovered it just won't.
5. `TEXTKOIN()` will then take over and first, dumps all the empty cells collected by `CHOOSE()`. Second, it creates one string from all the contents but uses a delimiter string that will set things up for `FILTERXML()`. So now you have only actual data. This step means you can use actual ranges of the moment, dynamic ranges you use cleverness to build, or just ranges with, say, a hundred extra rows "just to be sure."
6. Next layer is using `&` to stick the starting and ending text that are needed to make a real HTML string onto the start and end of the current string. This is then the input to the actual `FILTERXML()` function I keep mentioning. The "XPath" used at the end is all that's needed for a simple "single group, one kind of element only" string like this. This changes the data from being a single string back into real data elements that Excel can display in separate cells. At this point, all blanks have been removed. The data may contain duplicates.
7. `UNIQUE()` now takes over and removes the duplicates. One could `SORT()` if one desired.

Nothing complex or hard to follow once you know the parts. Understandable in a year when you go to update it.

There are some follow-on thoughts. First is that you mentioned different files, different collections of data. You'll need to make "an entry" of their ranges somewhere, somehow, for any approach, so you'll have to edit the formula, or something else to achieve that. This approach puts that entry at the beginning, not salted throughout the formula. You can use `INDIRECT)` with `CHOOSE()` so the editing can be done outside the formula in a data area that is populated with, say, sheet names. Those can be dynamic. Or populated with a several line macro that collects and dumps sheet names there for your formula to reference. And lots of variation on those themes. You can use helper areas for all things in general, not just the traditional "helper column" but a whole "helper sheet"... or two.

On a different tangent, `CHOOSE()` returns each column in order, in its own virtual column in the virtual table you build in the formula. If you put just that part into a cell, the array would look like that. `TEXTJOIN()` then reads across, then down, so it builds its string using all the first entries in all the columns, then all the second entries, etc. If you need each sheet's column to stay together for some reason, you need to wrap `CHOOSE()` with `TRANSPOSE()` before wrapping with the `TEXTJOIN()` so that when it reads across, it is reading "down" a column before going to its next row which has the second column's data, and so on.

I do not know what limit there is to how many ranges can be specified. You have one per sheet so I'm guessing no problem since it is likely either 127 or 255 so you have to have that many sheets before an issue arises. One can "stack" ranges in ranges, a kind of metaphorical iteration of them, and get lots more anyway so...

There's a great new function, `ARRAYTOTEXT()`, that I choose to not use in this example because it does not eliminate blanks like `TEXTJOIN()` does. When I build a multi-element HTML string for `FILTERXML()` to use, it can be a great text concatenator to use with its strict result rather than the comma-space separator for all elements because it gives me a way for Excel to see where to apply the different kinds of element tags. But here, `TEXTJOIN()` is unparalleled.